Zendesk App Framework - Google OAuth login
I'm trying to build a Zendesk app which will basically be a single page application hosted on an S3 bucket. It will be on the ticket_sidebar.
I'm having trouble getting past the google oauth setup as I cannot seem to figure out what to use as an redirect_uri for zendesk. Since it's an iframe, I'm assuming that there are some security concerns here so I'm fine with handling it via pop up. I keep getting the redirect_uri_mismatch and I can't seem to figure out how to get around it. I've add a few different domains within the Google setup.
I've tried doing this via window.open(redirect_uri, "popup"), to no avail.

The rediret uri error message should tell you what the uri is that you need to add.  Note the oauth window needs to be opened in a new browser window
